# PageSpeed или как кэшировать сторонние сайты

Tags: кэширование, pagespeed-insights

**Пожалуйста, не нужно писать** - "Забей на эти рекомендации Google".
**Суть вопроса** - PageSpeed Insights, очень часто ругается и просит кэшировать то, что не находится на моем серве (*google analytics, add This, etc..*).
Есть способ все-таки выполнить каким-то образом рекомендации Google, для увеличения итоговой оценки?
Возможно есть способ закрыть глаза Google на это?

Answer (score 1):

Кэширование не распространяется на внешние ресурсы. Иными словами, счетчики, сервисы рекомендаций и тому подобное вы кэшировать не сможете, поскольку не сможете повлиять на ответ сервера, который не находится под вашим контролем.

Проблему с внешними скриптами вы никак не решите, не перенеся их себе на сервер, а в случае со скриптами, вроде Google Analytics, это невозможно. Если хотите добиться 100 баллов из 100 в инструменте Page Speed Insights, то либо отключайте лишние сторонние скрипты, либо реализуйте похожий функционал самостоятельно на своем сервере.

Answer (score 1):

Гугл имеет ввиду как ни странно - кеширование в браузере.
К примеру php заголовком Cache-control или другими методами...
Но на некоторые сервисы он все ровно будет продолжать жаловаться, хотя некоторые сервисы как например yandex метрика, можно включить "Асинхронный код". Асинхронный код не блокирует и не влияет на скорость загрузки страницы сайта. Подобное и на других сервисах если это регулируется...

Answer (score 0):

Файл htaccess для Apache (корректируйте самостоятельно расширения требуемые для вашего сайта):

`FileETag none
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
   ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>`

Вы также можете самостоятельно выбирать требуемое вам из [этих модулей](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/), предлагаемых Гугл.